# subscriptions with parameters in polkadot.js api

Tags: polkadot-js, api, typescript, query

I am using React+Typescript and trying to retrieve data from a struc using a query subscription. I first tried the following in order to check that I'm retrieving the right data:

```
api.query.rolesModule.requestedRoles(address, (data: Codec) => {
      let data0 = data.toString();
      console.log('In session:' + data0);
    }
```

the string returned is the following:

```
In session:{"accountId":"5D1nJ8*************uc5e3AuB","role":"SELLER","block":2600,"proposalHash":"0xf0e4d3819cad58b9b7a521968202192601654106b063ed550d45e949cd0f9eec","proposalIndex":0,"sessionClosed":false,"approved":false}
```

Now what I really want are the `role` and `block` fields.
I tried the following:

```
 api.query.rolesModule.requestedRoles(
      address,
      ({ block, role }: { block: number; role: string }) => {
        let data0 = block;
        let data1 = role;
        console.log('In session:' + data0 + ' & ' + data1);
      }
```

but both results are undefined (which is not actually the case).
I did my best to emulate the example in the polkadot.js API doc, and had success in the following case to recover the free balance:

```
 api.query.system.account(address, ({ data: free }: { data: { free: BN } }) => {
      let { free: balance1 } = free;
```

What am I missing?

**Edit1:**
This is the storage I am trying to get data from:

```
#[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn get_requested_role)]
    pub type RequestedRoles<T: Config> =
        StorageMap<_, Twox64Concat, AccountIdOf<T>, Proposal<T>, OptionQuery>;
```

with proposal being:

```
pub struct Proposal<T: Config>{
    pub account_id: T::AccountId,
    pub role: Option<Accounts>,
    pub block: BlockNumberOf<T>,
    pub proposal_hash: T::Hash,
    pub proposal_index: u32,
    pub session_closed: bool, 
    pub approved: bool,
}
```

thanks in advance
Kazu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `toHuman()` it returns Human-parsable JSON structure with values formatted as per the settings.

This example will return you the values you are trying to get.

```js
api.query.templateModule.requestedRoles(address, (data: any) => {
        let data0 = data.toHuman();
        console.log(data0.role);
        console.log(data0.block);
});
```

`toHuman()` returns an any, if you want to have it all typed I suggest you create a parse function that get this any input an returns your custom type `Proposal`

Comment: Thanks Alex!! this exactly what I needed!!I only wish I could use another type than `any` for `data`, as I'm on TS......

Comment: WIth the Codec you were using doesn't work?

Comment: no, it does not find the different fields with codec